# Source a file in zsh when entering a directory

Tags: zsh, environment

Is there a way to source a particular file to set up the environment when entering a particular directory?  Sort of like what rvm does, but more general.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

IMHO you should not use an alias for this but add a hook to any directory change:

```
autoload -U add-zsh-hook
load-local-conf() {
     # check file exists, is regular file and is readable:
     if [[ -f .source_me && -r .source_me ]]; then
       source .source_me
     fi
}
add-zsh-hook chpwd load-local-conf
```

This hook function will run on any directory change.

FWIW, should you wish to change dirs *without* trigering the hooks, use `cd -q dirname`

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  I knew Joe's answer would work, but I knew there was a better way.  Thanks, `add-zsh-hook` is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: That is sweet.  I guess it's time for me to revisit the manual.

Comment: You could also simply try to source the file and ignore any errors: `source .source_me || true`.

Comment: The two strings with `autoload` and `add-zsh-hook` can be changed with one string - `chpwd_functions+=( load-local-conf )`

Answer (score 4):

What you want achieve is setting environment variables for a specific directory.

Compared with other tools designed for this, [`direnv`](https://github.com/direnv/direnv) is the best of them. One of the main benefit is that it supports **unload**ing the environment variables when you exit from that directory.

> `direnv` is an environment switcher for the shell. It knows how to hook into bash, zsh, tcsh, fish shell and elvish to load or **unload** environment variables depending on the current directory. This allows **project-specific environment** variables without cluttering the `~/.profile` file.

What makes `direnv` distinct between other similar tools:

- `direnv` is written in Go, **faster** compared with its counterpart written in Python
- `direnv` supports **unload**ing environment variables when you quit from the specific dir
- `direnv` covers many shells

Similar projects

- [Environment Modules](http://modules.sourceforge.net/) - one of the oldest (in a good way) environment-loading systems
- [autoenv](https://github.com/kennethreitz/autoenv) - lightweight; doesn't support unloads; slow written in Python
- [zsh-autoenv](https://github.com/Tarrasch/zsh-autoenv) - a feature-rich mixture of autoenv and [smartcd](https://github.com/cxreg/smartcd): enter/leave events, nesting, stashing (Zsh-only).
- [asdf](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf) - a pure bash solution that has a plugin system

Answer (score 1):

You could define a function that would perform the cd and then source a file.  This function will try to source .source_me in the new directory, if it exists:

```
mycd () {
builtin cd $@
[ $? -eq 0 -a -f .source_me ] && source .source_me
}
```

Enable using the function with

```
alias cd=mycd
```